# Query params seperator differs in Java and Javascript for semicolon

Tags: javascript, java, url

For such url `example.com?head=1&foot=1;id` Javascript URLSearchParams and Java URLEncodedUtils.parse returns different results.

Which one should I take into account?

Javascript :

```
let url = new URLSearchParams("?head=1&foot=1;id")
const params = Object.fromEntries(url.entries());
console.log(url) // --> { head: '1', foot: '1;id' }
```

Java:

```
 List<NameValuePair> params = URLEncodedUtils.parse("head=1&foot=1;id", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
 System.out.println(params); // --> [head=1, foot=1, id]
```

Comment: Java and Javascript are two completely different languages. These are two completely different code snippets, so it's shouldn't be a suprise that their string representations look different. What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are talking about the *semi-colon* part.

`URLEncodedUtils` you have used is now [deprecated](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-5.1.x/current/httpcore5/apidocs/org/apache/hc/core5/net/URLEncodedUtils.html) or you might be [using this](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.1/org/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)).

Semicolon was used to be a separator in query string, similar to what `&` does.

> In the recommendations of 1999, W3C recommended that all web servers support semicolon separators in addition to ampersand separators to allow application/x-www-form-urlencoded query strings in URLs within HTML documents without having to entity escape ampersands.

> Since 2014, W3C recommends to use only ampersand as query separator

Read about it here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Web_forms